# How to do select with 2 conditions into two columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one with users and another with errors. They have 2 relations. Errors can be fixed or submited by users. I want to show usernames with submited and fixed errors.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT usr.username, err.description AS ERROR_SOLVED
FROM Users usr, Errors err
WHERE err.solved_by_id=usr.id
UNION 
SELECT usr.username, err.description AS ERROR_SUBMITED
FROM Users usr, Errors err
WHERE err.submited_by_id=usr.id
```

Obviously it doesnt work, please help.

Comment: I think `OR` would achieve what the OP wants, since they are using `UNION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns must have the same descriptions.

```
SELECT usr.username, err.description AS ERROR, 1 as SOLVED
FROM Users usr, Errors err
WHERE err.solved_by_id=usr.id
UNION 
SELECT usr.username, err.description AS ERROR, 0 as SOLVED
FROM Users usr, Errors err
WHERE err.submited_by_id=usr.id
```

would work. You can also define a additional column to show which type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
Select usr.username, submittedErrs.description AS ERROR_SUBMITTED, 
   fixedErrs.description AS ERROR_SOLVED
from Users usr
left outer join Errors submittedErrs ON submittedErrs.submitted_by_id=usr.id
left outer join Errors fixedErrs ON fixedErrs.solved_by_id=usr.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT usr.username, err.description AS ERROR_SOLVED, 
       err2.description AS ERROR_SUBMITED
FROM Users AS usr 
JOIN Errors AS err ON err.solved_by_id=usr.id
JOIN Errors AS err2 ON err2.submited_by_id=usr.id
```

Answer (score 0):

When using alias names in union selects the first query determines the name. It is not possible to use other aliases for the same field in subsequent queries.

You should then add a type field to distinguish between errors and solutions.

If it is enough to have errors/solutions together without the type of action I would suggest a join with an OR in the on clause:

```
SELECT
    usr.username,
    err.description
FROM
     Errors err JOIN Users usr ON err.solved_by_id = usr.id OR err.submited_by_id=usr.id
```